# Why can i not add metadata to my Token-2022?

Tags: token-2022, spl-token-cli

Hello smart people of StackExchange,

I am currently playing arround with the new Token-2022, and i am attempting to create a token with Metadata directly in the mint account.

I am currently attempting using following CLI command:

```
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --enable-metadata
```

And i recive this error:

```
error: Found argument '--enable-metadata' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
Did you mean --enable-permanent-delegate?
```

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: FIY: I have already dowloaded the newest version of spl-token-cli.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and I had to update both spl-token-cli and solana tools to their latest versions https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools